# Google Bigquery use of substr, never returns back results

Tags: google-bigquery, substr

I have a table which has two sets of data, one set of data has information like

Type   |    Name   |     Id

PackagedDrug |Pseudoephedrine HCl Oral Tablet 120 MG| 110

PackagedDrug |Pseudoephedrine HCl Oral Tablet 60 MG|111

DrugName| Pseudoephedrine HCl| 112

---

What I want to do is join PackagedDrug with DrugName concepts, so get all Ids for Type PackagedDrug whose Name is matching with Name for Type DrugName. If I hardcode the Name for DrugName in the following query, it runs instantenously, but if I take out the hardcoding then it just keeps on running. Could you please  suggest me suitable ways to speed up the big query?

SELECT a.MSC_ID MSC_id, a.MSC_CONcept_type, a.concept_id, a.concept_name , b.concept_name

```
from 
(select MSC_id, MSC_CONcept_type, concept_id, concept_name  
   FROM [ClientAlerts.MSC_Concepts] 
  where MSC_CONcept_type in ('MediSpan.Concepts.PackagedDrug') ) a

CROSS JOIN
```

(select MSC_CONcept_type, concept_id, concept_name , length(concept_name) len
      FROM [ClientAlerts.MSC_Concepts] 
     where MSC_CONcept_type in ('MediSpan.Concepts.NamebasedClassification.DrugName')
      -- and concept_name in ('Pseudoephedrine HCl')
       ) b

where substr(a.concept_name,1,b.len)+' ' = b.concept_name

Thanks,
Savita

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with BigQuery itself. When you hardcode, your values are "filtered" way faster, because it doesn't have to check every row, since it looks for the hardcoded value.

If you don't use the hardcoded value, it will look at WAY more rows, compare ALL the rows from your first query with your second. Honestly, if you describe your use case properly here, I don't think of any way to do this faster.

But one question does come to mind. Why do you have a "type". It seems like it should be two different tables instead.

Comment: Hi, I created one of the type as another table, but it is still slow.

Comment: @SavitaMhetar, I never said creating two different tables would make it fast. It'll make it faster for sure. One thing to understand when you do joins is that the system tries to make every possible combination of rows.... how many rows on each table? this might simply be that you have so many rows the system WILL take a bit of time

Comment: one table has 2.5 million rows and other one has 78000 rows.